# How to use require in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I'm having trouble using the require in Ruby when I try to call the animal object.

```
#Classe Animal in file call animal.rb
class Animal
    def pular
        puts 'Toing! tóim! bóim! póim!'
    end

    def dormir
        puts 'ZzZzZ!'
    end
end
```

```
# Require rying to call the class Animal with arquivo app.rb
require './animal.rb'

animal = Animal.new

animal.pular
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
app.rb:3:in '': uninitialized constant Animal (NameError)
```

Comment: ok. my question is: 
I'm having trouble using the require in Ruby when I try to call the animal object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't specify the ".rb" as Ruby will search for matching ".rb" (or ".dll" or whatever)

Also the file is in the same directory, so you would use `require_relative`

```
require_relative 'animal'
```

Comment: I just corrected my program from require to require_relative, thanks.